# Jasperreports Textbox shouldn't split across page

Tags: jasper-reports

currently I'm trying to have a small PDF rendered with Jasperreports.

The PDF is really really simple, it contains some info on the left and a Text that changes in his size on the right.

However currently the List Subreport gots splitten so that the text box will got cut half if the last text box overflows the page, how to prevent that??

Here is my Report: http://pastebin.com/Yfct9qqc

I just want that if the element in the detail band overflows the page it should be printed on the next page, is that possible?
Currently it will just overflow the text field on the right or if i specify the left box get repeated..

Comment: We doesn't have data to reproduce the issue. Can you post the screenshot or downloaded file to see the issue?

Comment: I needed to cover the text with black boxes: http://i.imgur.com/PJRUmoy.png however there between the pages it will overflow. Also sometimes the bottom line will appear at the next page at the top. (Obviously the black box on the page after 57 should be grouped with the upper part)

Comment: Try adding `splitType="Prevent"` to band tag of detail band, like `<detail>
  <band splitType="Prevent">...`

Comment: that will keep my first page empty and just add a header.. and it will still overflow..

Comment: Looks like that now my First page is blank but the other error is fixed.. Still totally dump. I mean my detail band has a height of minimum 120. and it is a list, the first item won't overflow the page even with the header..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by setting split type to "Immediate" and changed the print order to "horizontal"